# Python's [<generator expression>] at least 3x faster than list(<generator expression>)?

Tags: python, performance, profiling

It appears that using [] around a generator expression (test1) behaves substantially better than putting it inside of list() (test2).  The slowdown isn't there when I simply pass a list into list() for shallow copy (test3).  Why is this?

Evidence:

```
from timeit import Timer

t1 = Timer("test1()", "from __main__ import test1")
t2 = Timer("test2()", "from __main__ import test2")
t3 = Timer("test3()", "from __main__ import test3")

x = [34534534, 23423523, 77645645, 345346]

def test1():
    [e for e in x]

print t1.timeit()
#0.552290201187


def test2():
    list(e for e in x)

print t2.timeit()
#2.38739395142

def test3():
    list(x)

print t3.timeit()
#0.515818119049
```

Machine: 64 bit AMD, Ubuntu 8.04, Python 2.7 (r27:82500)

Comment: Your list has only 4 (!!) ints in it.  The time you're measuring is probably dominated by creating the generator and such.

Comment: Note that if you make x even *slightly* larger, like `range(100)`, the results change dramatically: t2 is only 50% slower than t1, and t3 is far ahead.

Comment: the test2 example is a generator expression converted to a list, not a list comprehension

Comment: I'd never even consider the first two options. They're just redundant and longer (essentially, like `map id` in e.g. Haskell except that that language has a smart compiler).

Comment: Python can't be sure that `list` is the builtin `list` function without executing the program. On the other hand `[ .. ]` will always be a list so it can be optimized.

Comment: Corey: Thanks for the nit-picks on my question.  I've updated the title and body so that I don't confuse anyone else with my mistaken terminology.

Comment: delnan: I've simplified the problem I'm actually trying to solve so I could ask my question in a clear and coherent way.  I assure you that I'm not simply trying to do a shallow copy of the list.  I think haskell is cool too.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, my first step was to set the two tests up independently to ensure that this is not a result of e.g. the order in which the functions are defined.

```
>python -mtimeit "x=[34534534, 23423523, 77645645, 345346]" "[e for e in x]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.638 usec per loop

>python -mtimeit "x=[34534534, 23423523, 77645645, 345346]" "list(e for e in x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 usec per loop
```

Sure enough, I can replicate this. OK, next step is to have a look at the bytecode to see what's actually going on:

```
>>> import dis
>>> x=[34534534, 23423523, 77645645, 345346]
>>> dis.dis(lambda: [e for e in x])
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x0000000001F8B330, file "<stdin>", line 1>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              9 GET_ITER
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             13 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(lambda: list(e for e in x))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x0000000001F8B9B0, file "<stdin>", line 1>)
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             12 GET_ITER
             13 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice that the first method creates the list directly, whereas the second method creates a `genexpr` object and passes that to the global `list`. This is probably where the overhead lies.

Note also that the difference is approximately a microsecond i.e. utterly trivial.

---

### Other interesting data

This still holds for non-trivial lists

```
>python -mtimeit "x=range(100000)" "[e for e in x]"
100 loops, best of 3: 8.51 msec per loop

>python -mtimeit "x=range(100000)" "list(e for e in x)"
100 loops, best of 3: 11.8 msec per loop
```

and for less trivial map functions:

```
>python -mtimeit "x=range(100000)" "[2*e for e in x]"
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 msec per loop

>python -mtimeit "x=range(100000)" "list(2*e for e in x)"
100 loops, best of 3: 16.8 msec per loop
```

and (though less strongly) if we filter the list:

```
>python -mtimeit "x=range(100000)" "[e for e in x if e%2]"
100 loops, best of 3: 14 msec per loop

>python -mtimeit "x=range(100000)" "list(e for e in x if e%2)"
100 loops, best of 3: 16.5 msec per loop
```

Comment: great problem approach and explanation

Comment: Well, even for large randomized ists it does take a significant percentage longer, so it could indeed become an issue. Of course whoever writes `list(i for i in it)` instead of `list(it)` or (in case of sliceables) `it[:]` shouldn't be writing critical code in the first place ;) I also believe the laziness of genexprs (which has to be managed somewhere, of course) adds a bit of overhead.

Comment: Note: as THC4K said above, the fact that `list` could be shadowed (`list = None`) probably blocks any optimisations that could occur in the second version.

Comment: The reason the overhead doesn't go away as the list gets longer is that a lot of that overhead lies in the cost suspending and resuming a generator, which scales with the number of items in the sequence. The list comprehension form just builds the resulting list directly, no suspending or resuming required. To really dig into this, look at the dis results for the ``.func_code.co_consts[0]`` attribute on the lambda functions (``.__code__.co_consts[0]`` in Python 3).

Answer (score 9):

`list(e for e in x)` isn't a list comprehension, it's a `genexpr` object `(e for e in x)` being created and passed to the `list` factory function. Presumably the object creation and method calls create overhead.

Answer (score 2):

In python `list` name must be looked up in the module and then in builtins. While you cannot change what a list comprehension means a list call must just be a standard lookup + function call as it could be redefined to be something else.

Looking at the vm code generated for a comprehension it can be seen that it is inlined while a call to list is a normal call.

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     [x for x in xrange(4)]
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 DUP_TOP             
              4 STORE_FAST               0 (_[1])
              7 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
             13 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 GET_ITER            
        >>   17 FOR_ITER                13 (to 33)
             20 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
             23 LOAD_FAST                0 (_[1])
             26 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             29 LIST_APPEND         
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           17
        >>   33 DELETE_FAST              0 (_[1])
             36 POP_TOP             
             37 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> def bar():
...     list(x for x in xrange(4))
... 
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7fd1230cf468, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (xrange)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (4)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 GET_ITER            
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             25 POP_TOP             
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Possible translation: "Maybe the name 'list' has to be looked up. You can't change the meaning of a list comprehension (because it's part of the language syntax), I think list is looked up (at runtime) just like any other variable and then called as a function since it's possible to assign to 'list'."

Answer (score 1):

Your test2 is roughly equivalent to:

```
def test2():
    def local():
        for i in x:
            yield i
    return list(local())
```

The call overhead explains the increased processing time.