# Is a generator function faster than the corresponding for loops ((or iterations broadly) in Python

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am an beginner Python user and though I use Generators frequently(they are neat and concise, I want to understand if they are better than corresponding for loops(or iterations broadly) 
Faster : In sense of processing time and/or call overhead, even memory for that matter.
Example -: 
[Here, data is a dictionary object]

```
from math import sqrt

# **Generator** 
sum = sqrt(sum([pow(data[pers1][item] - data[pers2][item], 2) 
                for item in data[pers1] 
                if item in data[pers2]]))

# **For loop Equivalent** 
sum = 0
for item in data[pers1]:
    if item in data[pers2]:
         sum += sqrt(pow(data[pers1][item] - data[pers2][item], 2))
```

is the looping structure exactly the same, and if it would differ(in some other case), when would that be ? 
I tried to scale-up the input data and measure time (proxy for lookups), but it wasn't conclusive . I want to understand this more intuitively, i.e. if there's a difference at all.

[I am on python 2.7]

Code adapted from "Programming collective intelligence"
**Related question** : [Python's [<generator expression>] at least 3x faster than list(<generator expression>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402858/pythons-generator-expression-at-least-3x-faster-than-listgenerator-expres)

Comment: Usually `for` loops are the slowest

Comment: I think you had it right the first time round: *measure* then develop intuition, not the other way around.

Comment: your `sum` is actually using a `list` comp and **not** a genexp. You should remove the square brackets after `sum`

Comment: Every strategy has different trade-offs between CPU and memory usage, depending on the size of your dataset. Premature optimization is the root of all evil - if you have a performance problem then profile/optimize, if not, why sweat?

Comment: [What is better? For-loops or generator expressions (in cases like this)](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6927/24110)