# Performance while joining strings from mapping

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am looking at performance while joining strings from a mapping (`Mapping[str, str]`).

I have these two simple functions:

```
def nested(sequence, mapping):
    
    string = ""
    
    for x in sequence:
        
        string += mapping[x]
    
    return string
```

and

```
def flat(sequence, mapping):
    
    return "".join(mapping[x] for x in sequence)
```

In my project, I found a clear loss in performance while using the "flat" solution. Initially, I choose that solution because: "Flat is better than nested.", but quickly moved to the "nested" solution.

I ran a timeit test with simpler sequences and mappings:

```
letters = (
    "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m",
    "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"
)

mymapping = {x: x for x in letters}

mysequence = "mysequence"

print(timeit.timeit("nested(mysequence, mymapping)", globals=globals()))

print(timeit.timeit("flat(mysequence, mymapping)", globals=globals()))
```

and obtained:

```
In [683]: 0.675819274969399
0.965234256349504
```

This is 43% faster for the "nested" solution.
I observed several times faster situations in my project.

In the docs, we can read: "The preferred, **fast way** to concatenate a sequence of strings is by calling ''.join(sequence)". But I clearly see that "`+`" operator is faster in this configuration.

While I have no problem to stay with the "nested" solution:

Am I missing another "flat" solution? (no `sum()` possible with strings)

Do you have an explanation for this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: This depends highly on *what* you are joining. A mere 10 character string easily fits into various caches, for example, negating most costs. Compare e.g. ``mymapping = {x: x*1024 for x in letters}``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I found equivalent performance observations with your mymapping, as well as in my project where strings are complicated regular expressions. I think it is more linked to way each function works internally (cf. see flat_list and remap functions proposed in the other answers).

Answer (score 2):

When you use list comprehension, join is faster ony my end:

```py
def flat_list(sequence, mapping):
    return "".join([mapping[x] for x in sequence])
```

```py
2.5292927          # nested
2.3440613999999997 # flat_list
6.530926599999999  # flat
```

My guess is that it has something to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402858/pythons-generator-expression-at-least-3x-faster-than-listgenerator-expres). There seems to be some small overhead with the generator expression and repeated 10000 times this differences becomes visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this interesting information concerning generator expressions !

Answer (score 2):

> Am I missing another "flat" solution? (no sum() possible with strings)

The answer by Josef looks good so I'm just responding to this part. There's a much more elegant way (in my opinion), which seems to be faster than the alternatives too.

```
def remap(sequence, mapping):
    return ''.join(map(mapping.get, sequence))
```

---

```
# mysequence
1.098659     # nested
1.1296278    # flat_list
1.4904282    # flat
0.9128849    # remap

# mysequence * 10
8.5377648    # nested
8.814077     # flat_list
6.1268931    # flat
5.555387     # remap
```

Comment: Interesting, looks like built in types work very well with `map`.

Comment: It is indeed an elegant flat solution. More interesting is the speed performance ! Even if I have no particular knowledge in bytecode, I looked into the bytecode (as on the link provided by @Josef) of all 4 functions (nested, flat, flat_list from @Josef and your remap) and remap is way more simpler, which should explain the quickness. Thanks !